# Winforms combobox change displaytext after selecting a value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have an editable comboxbox bound to a List in a Winform application.

```
public class Address
    {
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public string DropDownText { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to display DropDownText when user expands the combobox, but I want show the DisplayText as Combobox's text after user has selected the dropdown item.

I can do this in WPF by using TextSearch.SetTextPath property. Is it possible in Winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
        comboBox1.Text = value;
    }));
}
```